# How to make an pivot table with values of chosen column instead of aggregated values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to get a table of min and max. But instead of values I want to see names of people that have this min or max value.
For example if I have a dataframe like this:

```
0  Name        Group    Salary  Age   
1  'Josh'      'A'      135000  50
2  'Bill'      'B'      130000  53
3  'Nikolaj'   'C'      125000  33
4  'Alfred'    'A'      130000  20
5  'Linda'     'C'      121000  25
6  'Yu'        'B'      134000  44
7  'Jeff'      'A'      120000  29
```

How could I use groupby or pivot_table to get frame that looks like this:

```
          Max                 Min
          Salary    Age       Salary    Age   
Group
A         'Josh'    'Josh'    'Jeff'    'Alfred'
B         'Yu'      'Bill'    'Bill'    'Yu'
C         'Nikolaj' 'Nikolaj' 'Linda'   'Linda'
```

If I try to use np.argmax or np.argmin it gives me indexes after groping so for example argmin for age in group B will give me 1 instead of 6. So i can't get correct indexes for original table to access 'Name' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with convert `Name` to index in first step, then change order of levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and sort `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Name')
         .groupby('Group')
         .agg([('Max','idxmax'),('Min','idxmin')])
         .swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False]))
print (df1)
             Max                 Min          
          Salary        Age   Salary       Age
Group                                         
'A'       'Josh'     'Josh'   'Jeff'  'Alfred'
'B'         'Yu'     'Bill'   'Bill'      'Yu'
'C'    'Nikolaj'  'Nikolaj'  'Linda'   'Linda'
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! At first it gave me a value error but it was my fault. I created datafdame so it all was an object type. After I changed 'Salary' and 'Age' to numerical type it works perfectly.